# Run Selenium Java Test in VSTS(Visual Studio Team Service)

Tags: java, selenium, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have written selenium java code to do the UI automation test in eclipse. Now, I want those code to be runed in VSTS. Problem is that there are lots of components which I am not clear how they are used under the tab "build & release". So I am looking for masters who can share with me the steps to achive my target. Thank you.

Comment: What details of selenium test of your project (e.g. selenium package, detail code)

Comment: @starain-MSFT for example ,  a couple of lines codes simulating user login in the web login page.

Comment: What selenium package you used? Could you share a simple sample on the OneDrive? What's the result if you try to run test through Maven task?

Comment: @starain-MSFT driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("username"));
  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("password"));
  driver.findElement(By.className("buttonSubmitForm")).click();
  
  String userName = driver.findElement(By.id("usrFullname")).getText();
  Assert.assertNotNull(userName);
  Assert.assertNotEquals(userName, "");

Comment: @starain-MSFT ,The test will be on firefox and chrome, so i think it should be interactive and browser maybe needed ?

Comment: @starain-MSFT <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

Comment: What's the result if you run it on local machine? If it works fine, then try to run test through Maven task in VSTS build. On the other hand, can you share a simple project on the OneDrive?

Comment: BTW: You need to setup the private build agent with interactive mode, the requirement for chrome: [ChromeDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

Answer (score 0):

If the test need to be run in interactive way, you need to setup a build agent with Interactive mode. (e.g. [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)), then run test through this build agent.

There is the Maven task that can run java test.

A related article: [Testing Java applications with VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-java)